# Windows Phone 8: Back Button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm new on windows phone platform. I'm trying to make a news application. On this application, user clicks and reads the article of news, after, user wants to came back to mainpage to see all news headers again, and will click the other news again.

But when the user comes back to mainpage after reading first article, user clicks second news header. But when user navigates to new page, first news article is still there.

I wanna ask this, is there any back button for user (after reading first news article) to use for clearing cache of article page when he or she presses to come back mainpage ?

I used this but it doesnt;

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

I wrote something under my httprequest, but it didnt worked for me too;

```
private void LiveLongListSelector_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "MYWEBAPIURL&rnd=" + new Random().Next(1,1000);
    HttpWebRequest hWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    hWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    hWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(ResponseLive_Completed, hWebRequest);
    hWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
    hWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
    hWebRequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
    hWebRequest.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
}
```

Can anyone help me to find that perfect back button or other thing ?

Thank you very much

Comment: On second page, which method do you use to get the news article that was chosen on the list on the main page?

Comment: i use "protected override void OnNavigatedTo" to get id of article and make the request below it..

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `NavigationService.GoBack();`
instead of using

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

It will clear all catch automatically.

or you can use `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` when coming again to read second article.
Use something like-

```
int a = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
while (a > number) //number is stack count when comes to main page first time
{
     this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
     a = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
}
```

Comment: NavigationService.goBack(); is better now but. I think the application keeps the data for 10 seconds.If i wait 10 second after coming my mainpage, clicking new article, no problem, it show.I counted its 10-15 seconds all time..

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods on `PhoneApplicationPage` that you can override and clean a cache: `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom`.

Comment: what will i write to "OnNavigatedFrom" method? I use "OnNavigatedTo" method to see details in my other page. Can you help me about it ?

Comment: @kgms21 NavigationService.GoBack() is right answer, in such case a page instance is not kept in memory and you don't need to apply any logic to clean your cached data. I was confused, I thought question was concerning cache cleaning, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use the following code in NavigatedTo() method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null);
}
```

Hope, that helps.