# NavigationService.GoBack Not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.

My app page structure

1.WelcomePage(GetLocation)->

2.MainPage.xaml (Contain Six Button Ex:Hotels,Park,Temple...)->

3.Hotels(List of hotels present Click any of the Hotel)->

4.MoreDetailsPage(About the particular hotel In Browser with in the app)

Every thing work well upto reach MoredetailPage.In Moredetailpage I use NavigationService.GoBack(); OnBackkeyPress Event. If I press Back Key It's just close and exit from the App.

My Coding For Every Page:-

**WelcomePage.xaml**

On revgeocoding_QueryCompleted Event.

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Mainpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

**MainPage.xaml**

On Click Event.

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Hotels.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Remove BackEntry for WelcomePage.xaml

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

**Hotels.xaml**

On Listbox Tap Event.

```
   this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Moredetailswebpage.xaml?Businessname={0}", passvalue), UriKind.Relative));
```

**Moredetailswebpage.xaml**

PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded Event

```
minbrowser.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
```

OnBackKeyPress

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

If I click hardware backkey from the MoreDetailpage.xaml . It's just close and exit from the app.

Plz tell how to solve this problem.Where I made mistake.

Comment: I think app is crashing on back key press? If not have you checked is there any entry present in backstack?

Comment: @vits How to check entry present in backstack.

Comment: NavigationService.CanGoBack();

Comment: Also,total entries like this,
    int stackSize = 0;
    foreach (var screen in NavigationService.BackStack)
    {
        stackSize++;
    }

Comment: if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                this.NavigationService.GoBack();
            }   It's Go inside the this.NavigationService.GoBack();

Comment: try using this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Moredetailswebpage.xaml?Businessname=" + passvalue), UriKind.Relative));

Comment: @vyas_27 I need to use the String.format and Businessname{0}

Comment: @vits  i use Your Stacksize method . value come in stacksize is 2

Comment: the above code will do the same, it will pass your Businessname as querystring to navigating page. As well as try using NavigationService.Navigate() instead of this.NavigationService.Navigate()

Comment: Its 2 ,then you can remove GoBack from backkey event,AND no RemoveBackEntry should be there in previous page's OnNavigatedTo method.

Comment: @Vyas_27  Error occur For your code "No overload for method 'Navigate' takes 2 arugument"

Comment: @vits But I'm not using any OnNavigatedTo method in Hotels.xaml page

Comment: @vits it should Navigate back to Hotels Page but instead it's just exiting the application.

Comment: @vits Yes I check with break point  In backkey press it's go to hotels page and exit form it

Comment: Is Hotel page present in backstack before back navigation.

Comment: I'm not clear what you ask

Comment: @Gurunathan try adding break point at navigatingto event in main page and see if it triggers on back key pressed.

Comment: @Vyas_27 No It's not triggers the back key

Comment: When you are at Moredetailswebpage then on pressing back key try checking weather from hotelpage is it going back to main page or due to some exception in hotel's page the app is crashing because if the app is reaching the hotel's page means your backstack and back key are working properly.

Comment: @Vyas_27 From Hotels Page to Mainpage Works correctly and from mainpage it's just exit the app work correctly

Comment: then remove the overridden back key pressed event from Moredetailswebpage & try using this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Moredetailswebpage.xaml?Businessname=" + passvalue), UriKind.Relative));

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8: Back Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065713/windows-phone-8-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

You said that on the *Back Key Press* your Application would quit?
here's what an example to not make it quit.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{

      //Forces the app not to quit
      e.Cancel = true;          

}
```